# Término en español para una victoria por W.O

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Una [victoria por W. O.](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkover) (*walkover*) es:

> una victoria otorgada a una persona o equipo cuando no hay más competidores, porque se retiraron, fueron descalificados o no asistieron.

El término está cogido directamente del inglés. ¿Hay algún término en español más adecuado para una victoria así?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En español, lo más adecuado en sentido técnico sería "victoria por **incomparecencia**":

> **[incomparecencia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LGUGGNK)**
>
> 1. f. Falta de asistencia a un acto o lugar en que se debe estar presente.

También se usa mucho "victoria por **abandono**", sobre todo cuando dicho abandono se produce en medio del encuentro:

> **[abandonar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=01yxXv6)**
>
> 6. intr. En el juego o en el deporte, dejar de luchar, darse por vencido.

En el caso específico de descalificación, se usaría "victoria por descalificación".

En sentido figurado, como parece que se usa también a veces cuando el oponente es demasiado fácil...

> [walkover](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/walkover)
>   : a one-sided contest : an easy or uncontested victory

... se usa muchas veces "**paseo**":

> [**ser** algo **un paseo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S3qI7Xz)
>
> 1. locs. verbs. coloqs. Resultar muy cómodo o muy fácil de hacer.

Comment: al comparar con 3 eventos, tendría que evaluar caso a caso:

Comment: En 1973, la URSS se negó a ir a jugar contra Chile para la eliminatoria del mundial de Alemania 1974, la FIFA dio como resultado un 2:0 por w.o.. Los términos incomparecencia o descalificación, suenan apropiados. En 1938, por la anexión austriaca, el partido de la copa del mundo Suecia vs. Austria fue ganado por la primera por W.O. lo que valida los términos propuestos. En Londres 1908 solo hubo un participante en la final de 400 m, pues se descalificó a un participante y 2 compatriotas decidieron no participar. Ahí no me suenan TAN bien (aunque puede usarse). Cualquier otra opción, bienvenida